# React Redux and React Router connect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, react-router

when I try to dispatch an event on logout function it shows me an error I think the way I am connecting Redux is wrong but I'm not sure can anyone solve this? 
**Logout Function**

```
 Auth.logout(() => {
      Firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
          this.props.updateState();
      });
 })
```

**Dispatch**

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
       return{
          updateState: () => dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_REDUX_STATE'})
       }
}
```

**Export with connect and withRouter**

```
 export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Navigation))
```

**Navigation Component**

```
class Navigation extends Component {
logoutHander(){
        Auth.logout(() => {
            Firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
                this.props.updateState();
            });
        })
}
render(){
    return(
        <div className="custom-container-fluid">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md text-center">
                <div className="container">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">FG</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    {
                        Auth.isAuthenticated() === true  ?
                        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/home"><i className="fas fa-home" style={{marginRight: '3px'}}></i>Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/myrecipe"><i className="fas fa-stream" style={{marginRight: '3px'}}></i>My Recipes</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item"  onClick={this.logoutHander}>
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/"><i className="fas fa-user" style={{marginRight: '3px'}}></i>Logout</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item upload-nav">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/uploadRecipe"><i className="fas fa-upload" style={{marginRight: '3px'}}></i>Upload Recipe</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        :
                        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/login"><button className="btn nav-btn-signup"><i className="fas fa-user" style={{marginRight: '3px'}}></i>Login</button></Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Error I am getting is **Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

Comment: What kind of error you have got?

Comment: Show Navigation component and how you are using that updateState prop

Comment: cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

This reference not possessed inside the firebase method,

can you pass this instance value to some other variable, Current instance will be copied when the function till complete

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
logoutHander(){
        const self = this;
        Auth.logout(() => {
            Firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
                self.props.updateState();
            });
        })
}
```

Comment: add this code in the class constructor(props) {
  super(props);}

Comment: Thanks for your help Palani samy!! I solved this by adding this.props.updateState() outside the Auth.logouth function